# How to declare "any" module in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I need to migrate step by step some large project from js to typeScript.

I rewrite on of the files in ts and i want to specify that other files at this moment can contain any content.

For example something like that:

```
declare module jsModule:any;
var obj:jsModule.cls = new jsModule.cls()
```

But it does not work in this moment. I need to specify each exported class/function/variable in module declaration.

Can i declare external module as "any" in some fast way?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For an external module with no exposed types and any values:

```
declare module 'Foo' {
  var x: any;
  export = x;
}
```

This won't let you write `foo.cls`, though.

If you're stubbing out individual classes, you can write:

```
declare module 'Foo' {
    // The type side
    export type cls = any;
    // The value side
    export var cls: any;
}
```

Comment: var x: any;
^^^ Unexpected token var

Comment: I'm getting the error "An export assignment cannot be used in a namespace" with the `export = x;` line underlined.  Any idea why?

Comment: You forgot quotes around the module name