# Why does this generic Typescript definition fail?

Tags: typescript

**Is there any one line simple way of importing an entire library and disregarding its type?**

This doesn't work. Why not?

[image]

Then I tried this (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729668/how-to-declare-any-module-in-typescript)) but it doesn't work either.

[image]

---

**Update**

This definition works, but I still want a one line version that we don't have to mantain:

```
declare module 'joi' { 
  export const validate: any;
  export const object: any;
  export const string: any;
  export const required: any;
  export type ValidationOptions = any;
  export type ValidationResult<any> = any;
  export type ObjectSchema = any;
}
```

Comment: Try without the `<any>`: `Promise<Joi.ValidationResult>`.

Comment: That part is definitely correct. My code was working fine when I used the DefinitelyTyped library. But as I found mistakes in it I had to drop the official definition in favour of making my own `any` definition somehow.

Comment: Can you redefine the declaration to "export type ValidationResult<T> = any;"?

Comment: What I don't understand is why you export ValidationResult as a type and not as an interface with <T> as they do in definitelyTyped `export interface ValidationResult<T> {...}` ? That could be the source of the problem. You can also try to impor directly the type `import {ValidationResult} from 'file.d.ts';`

Comment: As long as my code compiles either way I don't mind if it's T or any.  But how to use the Joi framework with only a one line definition, or no definition?