# imprt node_module in typescript (angular2) app

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, import, module

I try to load [this](https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema) module in my typescript add. 
First I added the npm package and the module has been installed correctly in my `node_modules` folder as `simpl-schema`.
Since there are no typings for this package I added this line:

```
declare var SimpleSchema: any;
```

I tried to import the package with `import * as SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';` and got the message `Cannot find module 'simpl-schema'`. I think a got this since `simpl-schema` doesn't contain type information but I'm not sure.

I found tons of questions regarding this topic here, on reddit and other forums with a lot of suggestions which doesn't work for my setup. So I'm wondering whats the right way to this.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you're getting `Cannot find module 'simpl-schema'` because types are either not available, or types are not setup properly.

Using `declare var SimpleSchema: any;` in your ts says that `SimpleSchema` is a variable (`var`) of type `any` declared outside the scope of that file. The above will not impact the result of importing `simpl-schema` directly. An example would be adding something like `declare const window: any;` to get access to the `window` object, if it weren't already defined for you, elsewhere.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729668/how-to-declare-any-module-in-typescript) for a way to leverage the `any` type when looking to import modules that don't have types available.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this case types are not available since simpl-schema doesn't contain a .d.ts. But I still don't know what I have to do to use simpl-schema in my app. If I add `declare var SimpleSchema: any;` the compiling process works fine but the when running in browser the SimpleSchema object couldn't be found. So I tried to add `<script src="./node_modules/simpl-schema/dist/main.js"></script>` to my `index.html` which also doesn't work.

Comment: Is `SimpleSchema` being made available globally from `main.js` (attaching `SimpleSchema` to `window`)? Typescript just trusts you when you use `declare var` to inform the compiler that that value will be available wherever it will run, but when the compiled output runs, `SimpleSchema` will need to actually be there.